# Get a complete name of a directory in Python

Tags: python

My SO is Raspbian in a Raspberry Pi 2.
Im working with nano 2.2.6
Im a newbie in Python.
I want to program a temperature sensor D18B20.
I got a fantastic manual:
[Raspberry Pi temperature sensor](http://www.reuk.co.uk/DS18B20-Temperature-Sensor-with-Raspberry-Pi.htm).
When I list the devices with:

```
  ls -l /sys/bus/w1/devices/
```

I would like to get the name of the directory asociated to the thermometer as 28*. I know the name but i need to make a program to get the name.
I was working with this code. But i can't get the full name of the directory.

```
  import os
  name = os.path.basename ("sys/bus/w1/devices/28*")
  print (name)
```

Thank you very much for your time and patience
Best regards

## Edited Version 0.1b

```
import glob, os.path
import time

paths = glob.glob("/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-*")
path_names= [os.path.basename(path) for path in paths]
l = list (path_names)
name = l[0] 
path_names = "".join(name)
print name

while 1:
    tempfile = open ("/sys/bus/w1/devices/name/w1_slave")
    #thetext = tempfile.read()
    #tempfile.close()
    #tempdata = thetext.split("\n"[1].split(" ")[9]
    #temperature = float(tempdata[2:])
    #temperature = temperature / 1000
    #print temperature
    #time.sleep (1)
```

Comment: Note that your command-line example uses the path `/sys/bus/w1/devices`, but your code leaves out the `w1` component.

Comment: Thanks, i changed but i cant get the complet name.

Comment: What exactly do you expect as the output? I don’t really understand what you mean by “full name of the directory”.

Comment: Your link is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a google search of your link, it seems like your temperature sensor follows a naming pattern of 28-*. You could use this:

```
import glob, os.path
paths = glob.glob("/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-*")
path_names = [os.path.basename(path) for path in paths]

if len(path_names) > 0:
   first_sensor = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(path_names[0], "w1_slave"))
   while True:
       # read from sensor file
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your hep. I got it. Now i need to get the name   of "28-*" as string..

Comment: You can do that with os.path.basname() function. I have edited my answer above to reflect this.

Comment: Again thanks for your valuable help. I did the changes. They worked but i still have problems. I cant open the directory. I edited in the main question. Thanks for your patience, again.